# Прослушивание изменений в таблице mysql через nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, события

Появилась потребность написать бота, который отслеживает изменения в таблице mysql и выполняет какое-то действие. Как лучше всего это написать? Знаю про  `mysql-events`, но хотелось бы каких-то понятных примеров.

Comment: *Знаю про mysql-events* Интересно, что? подавать сигналы наружу оно не умеет. Так что либо поллинг рабочих таблиц (при условии, что там есть поля с автовременем - и всё равно трындец производительности), либо триггерная логика, которая пишет факт изменения в служебную таблицу, и поллинг (с очисткой прочитанного) уже из неё.

Comment: @Akina что вы посоветуете? Как лучше реализовать?

Comment: Да я понятия не имею, что лучше НА ВАШЕЙ СИСТЕМЕ. Может, Вы способны написать свой пуш-сервер, и написать и подключить в MySQL UDF, которая будет с ним общаться.

Comment: @Akina zongji? Может ли он выполнять данную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Вариант решения задачи

**Краткая схема такая:**

- Подключаемся к базе
- Получаем контрольную сумму таблицы с помощью SQL запроса `CHECKSUM
  TABLE 'имя_таблицы';`
- Бесконечно повторяем запрос с необходимым интервалом и сравниваем новую контрольную сумму с
  предыдущей

Если контрольная сумма отличается, значит данные таблицы изменились.

```
    const mysql = require('mysql2')

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        database: 'mydatabase'
    })

    var lastCheckSum = null

    setInterval(() => {
        connection.query('CHECKSUM TABLE users', function (e, r) {
            if (r[0]['Checksum'] == lastCheckSum || !lastCheckSum) {
                console.log('Table not changed!')
            } else {
                console.log('Table changed!')
            }
            lastCheckSum = r[0]['Checksum']
        })
    }, 1000)
```